# Auto Date/Time when cell range contains values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a few questions that center around what I'm looking for but I have not been able to figure out how to refactor for my use case.

I am trying to setup a script in GSheet that will enter the current date and time in a specific cell when every cell in the range contains input.

So, e.g. if cells I2 through P2 contain text(any at all), enter the current date and time in cell H2, if not then leave empty. I would then need to apply this to each row (e.g. I3 through P3, and so on).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a good place to start. If you are looking to make adjustments I recommend looking at the SpreadsheetApp documentation. (Namely the getRange method.)

### Link to documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

I did a very basic test and it appears to be working as intended.

```
function test() {

var date = new Date();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var range = sheet.getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow(),8).getValues();

for (var i = 2; i < range.length +2; i++){

for (var k = 0; k < range[i-2].length; k++){

if (range[i-2][k] !== ""){
sheet.getRange(i, 8, 1, 1).setValue(date);
break

}//END OF IF STATEMENT
}//END OF K LOOP
}//END OF I LOOP
}//END OF FUNCTION
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.